# Combining ListDatasets and ListFields to return geodatabase contents to CSV--one script prints attributes and another returns feature class counts

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, csv

New to Python. I'm trying to combine two scripts I found online that use the ListDatasets and ListFields tools. One loops through all the features of a geodatabase and writes the name of the feature dataset, feature class, and the number of features to a .csv file. To that one I would like to add the other that prints to the screen information about the attributes--name, type, and length. I would like all of this printed to a single .csv file like this:

[image]

The ListDatasets Script:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\Redfish\Test.sde\Test.DBO.Structures\Test.DBO.HospitalBldg"


file = open("C:\Users\Redfish\Desktop\DatabaseDictionary.csv", "w")
file.write('Dataset, LayerName, NoOfRecords' + '\n')

for fds in arcpy.ListDatasets('*','feature') + ['']:
                for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*','',fds):
                                result = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fc).getOutput(0))
                                file.write(fds + ', ' + fc + ', ' + str(result) + '\n')

file.close()
```

The ListFields Script

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\Redfish\Test.sde\Test.DBO.Structures\Test.DBO.HospitalBldg"

fields = arcpy.ListFields("C:\Users\Redfish\Test.sde\Test.DBO.Structures\Test.DBO.HospitalBldg")
for field in fields:
    print("{0}\{1}\{2}"
          .format(field.name, field.type, field.length))
```

Comment: While you *can* use any indentation scheme in Python, you really [ought](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to use **four spaces**.  This will make your code consistent (and readable on small-screen devices on GIS SE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first script `fc` is your feature class. After `for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*','',fds):` add your `ListFields` script.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\Redfish\Test.sde\Test.DBO.Structures\Test.DBO.HospitalBldg"


file = open("C:\Users\Redfish\Desktop\DatabaseDictionary.csv", "w")
file.write('Dataset, LayerName, NoOfRecords' + '\n')

for fds in arcpy.ListDatasets('*','feature') + ['']:
                for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*','',fds):
                                result = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fc).getOutput(0))
                                fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
                                #start gathering info
                                for field in fields:
                                    #add field info
                                    vals = [fds, fc, result, field.name, field.type, field.length]
                                    #write one line per field
                                    file.write(",".join (map (str, vals)) + "\n")
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks very much. I was pretty close.